# PHP Password Encrypting Issues

Tags: php, authentication, password-hash

I am trying to create a login and registration system for my website, however I would like to use a more secure password encryption method than md5 but I am running into issues.

```
function register_user($register_data) {
array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
$register_data['password'] = password_hash($register_data['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
email($register_data['email'], 'Activate your account', "
Hello " . $register_data['first_name'] . ",\n\nYou need to activate your account, so use the link below:\n\nhttp://thepuzzler.net/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email'] . "&email_code=" . $register_data['email_code'] . " \n\n -ThePuzzler");      }
```

This is my register function which I haven't had issues with because when a user registers, the BCRYPT password is stored in my database. The issue is verifying the user.

```
function login($username, $password) {

$user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
$username = sanitize($username);
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);

return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;     }
```

That is my login system and when I try to login, I fetch my own error of the username or password is incorrect. This sis because I think that the encrypted passwords are not matching up. So I think it has to do with the line where I create the `$password` variable and encrypt it.

Also, in my database the password column is a varchar(64). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The [password_hash](http://php.net/password_hash)() function generates an inidividual salt on each call. To verify the password, you will need the [password_verify](http://php.net/password_verify)() function.

So you will need to get the password hash from the database and pass it alongside the entered password to password_verify().

**Edit:**
Like this:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $usernameForDb = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $hashFromDb = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$usernameForDb'")); 
    $isValid = password_verify($password, $hashFromDb); 
    if ($isValid) {
        // user is accepted, get userID
        return user_id_from_username($username);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying but password_verify() returns a bool so I don't know how you can have a bool equal the password in the database.

Comment: $hashFromDb  = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")); $isValid = password_verify($passwordEnteredByUser, $hashFromDb); if ($isValid) {// user is accepted, get userID}

Comment: This code appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, @ScottArciszewski, you are right. I added real_escape to the code